# Elementary proof of irreducibility criterion

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, alternative-proof, irreducible-polynomials

From ``Problems from the Book'' by Andreescu and Dospinescu, the following irreducibility criterion is presented:

Let $f$ be a monic polynomial with integer coefficients and let $p$ be a prime.  If $f$ is irreducible over the integers, and $\sqrt[p]{(-1)^{\deg(f)} f(0)}$ is irrational, then $f(x^p)$ is also irreducible over the integers.

I've reproduced the proof here.  I'd like to see an elementary proof that does not rely on field theory, if possible.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I retagged, but really both (abstract-algebra) and (field-theory) do not belong. I removed only the second so as not to make too drastic a change from the original. The objects in the question have elementary definitions, and the question requests a proof without (abs-alg) or (field-theory), so ...

Comment: Should the hypothesis read $f$ irreducible over $\mathbb Q$? Otherwise there's no guarantee of a complex root as in the proof.

Comment: @ntropy If $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, then it's irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by Gauss' Lemma.

Comment: Ah my mistake, meant to say irreducible over $\mathbb R$. The example I had in mind was $x^2 - 2$.

Comment: My answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562010/for-which-monic-irreducible-fx-in-mathbb-zx-is-fx2-also-irreducibl gives an elementary proof in the case $p=2$.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem possible to generalize it  to arbitrary $p$ without using a bit of theory of the field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ where $\zeta_p$ is a primitive $p$th root of unity.  (This doesn't come up for $p=2$ since then $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)=\mathbb{Q}$.)

Answer (score 0):

For a monic polynomial $g(x) = \prod_i (x-\alpha_i) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, let $\mathcal{P}(g(x)) := \prod_i (x-\alpha_i^p) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be the monic polynomial whose roots are the $p$th powers of the roots of $g(x)$. The operator $\mathcal{P}$ has some nice easily-verified properties:

- $\mathcal{P}(gh) = \mathcal{P}(g)\mathcal{P}(h)$
- $\mathcal{P}(g(x^p)) = g(x)^p$
- For $p \ne 2$, $\mathcal{P}(g)(0) = g(0)^p$.
- For $p = 2$, $\mathcal{P}(g)(0) = (-1)^{\deg{g}}g(0)^2$

Now let $f(x)$ be monic irreducible, and by way of contradiction let $f(x^p) = g(x)h(x)$ be a factorization of $f(x^p)$ into non-constant factors.

Then $\mathcal{P}(g(x))\,\mathcal{P}(h(x)) = \mathcal{P}(f(x^p)) = f(x)^p$ is a power of the irreducible polynomial $f(x)$, so each of the factors on the left is also a power of $f(x)$. Write $\mathcal{P}(g(x)) = f(x)^k$ with $1\le k \le p-1$.

Then for $p \ne 2$, $f(0)^k = \mathcal{P}(g)(0) = g(0)^p$. Since $f(0)^k$ is a $p$th power and $k$ is not divisible by $p$, $f(0)$ is also a $p$th power. Then since $p$ is odd, $(-1)^{\deg f}f(0)$ is a $p$th power as well.

For $p = 2$, the only possibility for $k$ is $1$, so $\deg{g} = \deg{f}$ and $f(0) = \mathcal{P}(g)(0) = (-1)^{\deg g}g(0)^2 = (-1)^{\deg{f}}g(0)^2$. Hence $(-1)^{\deg f}f(0)$ is a perfect square.