# $X^4-4X^2-1$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I want to show, that $X^4-4X^2-1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.
Since there are no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$ it has to be:

$(X^4-4X^2-1)=(X^2+aX+b)(X^2+cX+d)$

Comparision of the coefficients shows that this can not hold over $\mathbb{Q}$. But I am searching for an easier way to show this which uses less calculation.

I tried this:

$X^4-4X^2-1=X^4-4X^2+4-5=(X^2-2)^2-5=(X^2-2-\sqrt{5})(X^2-2+\sqrt{5})$

Which is obviously not in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ anymore.
But would this calculation be enough to show, that $X^4-4X^2-1$ is irreducible.
How do I know, that this is the only possible way to factor it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't answer the exact question being asked here, but as a tangential aside, this polynomial is irreducible $\pmod{p}$ for a small $p$ and hence irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Look up the rational root theorem.

Comment: @KajHansen: But using the reduction theorem (which I think you are refering too) not involve a similar calculation, which might be easier?

Comment: @DougM: The rational root theroem should not work here, since the degree of the polynomial is 4. The non existence of a root does not mean the polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: @Cornman, the nice thing about it is that the number of irreducible quadratic polynomials in this particular $\mathbb{F}_p$ is quite small--small enough to just try them all.  On the other hand, the infinitude of polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ makes the current endeavor tricky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your polynomial has no rational roots. Therefore, if it was reducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then it would have to be the product of two quadratic polynomials $p_1(X),p_2(X)\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$. Each of them either has to real roots or two complex non-real roots.

The roots of your polynomial are $\pm\sqrt{\sqrt5+2}$ and $\pm i\sqrt{\sqrt5-2}$. Of these, only the last two are complex non-real.  But$$\left(X-i\sqrt{\sqrt5-2}\,\right)\left(X+i\sqrt{\sqrt5-2}\,\right)=X^2-2+\sqrt5\notin\mathbb{Q}[X].$$Therefore, your polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: Therefore my factorisation would be enough to show that the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[X]$?

Comment: @Cornman I don't see why. The fact that your decomposition does not work doesn't imply that no decomposition works. For instance, $$x^4-5x^2+6=\left(x^2-\left(\sqrt2+\sqrt3\right)x+\sqrt6\right)\left(x^2+\left(\sqrt2+\sqrt3\right)x+\sqrt6\right),$$but $x^4-5x^2+6$ *is* reducible, since it is equal to $(x^2-3)(x^2-2)$.

Answer (score 4):

Let's write $f(x)=x^4-4x^2-1$.  Note that since $f(x)=f(-x)$, the roots of $f$ come in positive and negative pairs; say the roots are $a$, $-a$, $b$, and $-b$.  Up to renaming the roots, then, there are two cases of factorizations with integer coefficients that $f$ could have.  We could have $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ where $g(x)=(x-a)(x+a)=x^2-a^2$ and $h(x)=(x-b)(x+b)=x^2-b^2$.  But that would mean that $x^2-4x-1$ factors as $(x-a^2)(x-b^2)$, and we know $x^2-4x-1$ is irreducible.

The other possibility is that we have a factorization like $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ with $g(x)=(x-a)(x-b)=x^2-(a+b)x+ab$ and $h(x)=(x+a)(x+b)=x^2+(a+b)x+ab$.  In this case, though, $ab$ would be an integer and the constant term of $f(x)$ would be the square of $ab$.  Since the constant term is $-1$, this is impossible.

More generally, a similar argument shows that if $e(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is irreducible and monic of degree $n$, then $f(x)=e(x^2)$ is irreducible unless its constant term is $(-1)^n$ times a perfect square.  See the answers to [For which monic irreducible $f(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$ , is $f(x^2)$ also irreducible in $\mathbb Z[x]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562010/for-which-monic-irreducible-fx-in-mathbb-zx-is-fx2-also-irreducibl) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a way to show this by reduction mod $p$:

To see $f$ is irreducible, we use reduction mod 3, which gives $\bar f=x^4-x^2-1$. $\bar f$ clearly has no roots in $\mathbb Z_3$. In $\mathbb Z_3[x]$, the only (monic) irreducible degree 2 polynomials are $$x^2-x+1,x^2-x-1,x^2+x-1,\\x^2+1$$
If $\bar f$ is reducible, then it must be a product of two of them.
A few computations show that it can't be the case. Hence $\bar f$ is irreducible and so is $f$.