# Degree and basis of field extension $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}}]$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I want to find the degree and basis of the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}})$.

let $\alpha=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}}$.
$$\alpha^2=2+\sqrt{5},\quad \alpha^4-4\alpha^2-1=0.$$

So possible minimal polynomial $f(X)=X^4-X^2-1$. $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ since its roots are all non rationals and so its possible factors are of degree $2$  not $1$. Looking at the roots shows irreducibility and hence $f$ is the minimal polynomial and degree of extension is $4$.

My problem is with the basis. Since $\alpha^2=2+\sqrt{5}$, then $\sqrt{5}$ is in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. So $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ has degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ has degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$  using Tower Law gives degree $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ over $\mathbb{Q}\sqrt{5}$ is $2$.

So a basis  for $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is the product of the bases.
$$B=\{1,\sqrt{5},\alpha,\alpha \sqrt{5}\}$$

Is the basis and method correct?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2446699/x4-4x2-1-irreducible-over-mathbbqx

Comment: is the basis correct? i wrote this in an exam I want to make sure @lhf

Comment: Hey, do we not need to consider inverses, so $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+2}}=\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+2}) \, ?$$

Answer (score 1):

This is correct.

Let $L/K/F$ be a tower of field extensions.

Let $\{ k_i\}_i$ be a basis for $K/F$.

Let $\{ l_j \}_j$ be a basis for $L/K$.

Then the product $\{ k_i \cdot l_j \}_{i,j}$ is a basis for $L/F$.

This is reasonable as it has the correct size by tower law.

We can express every element $l \in L$ in terms of this basis. First expand $l = \sum_{j} l_j c_j$ with each $c_j \in K$, then expand each $c_j = \sum_{i} k_i d_{j,i}$ and we have $l = \sum_{j,i} (l_j k_i) d_{j,i}$ with each $d_{j,i} \in F$.

Secondly it is a linearly independent basis, suppose $0 = \sum_{j,i} (l_j k_i) d_{j,i}$ then you can group the terms as a sum of $K$ coefficients in the basis of $L/K$ so it will be zero if each coefficient is zero. Now you can apply linear independence of $K/F$.